# mvn one:convert don't work? 

Tags: java, maven

Finally, I found that some dependency of maven-one-plugin don't install properly. but fix them this plugin work.

question fixed :

I am working on convert a maven 1 project to maven 2 project so I just run this command at the folder of the project:

```
mvn one:convert
```

then get a error:

```
 [INFO] Internal error in the plugin manager executing goal
  'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-one-plugin:1.2:convert': 
 Unable to find the mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-one-plugin:1.2:convert' in 
 the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-one-plugin'
 org.apache.maven.model.v3_0_0.PatternSet
```

Anybody know the reason ? Sorry I just so green on maven and the task is urgent...

Answer (score 2):

Try `maven-one-plugin:convert`

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [does exist](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-one-plugin/) in central repo

Just wondering if you are running this command using maven 1.  If so, can you install maven 2/3 and try?

**Edit 1**:

Downloaded a sample Maven 1 project from [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/start/ten-minute-test.html).
Ran `mvn convert:one` using the latest maven (maven 3).
Worked successfully

```
D:\work\sample-echo>mvn one:convert
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-one-plugin:1.2:convert (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Adding report org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-changes-plugin
[INFO] There are 14 plugin relocators available
[INFO] Writing new pom to: D:\work\sample-echo\pom.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.950s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 22 15:01:52 IST 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the plugin manual and check if your configuration matches the required configuration.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-one-plugin/usage.html